File transfer between 2 different IIS servers with virtual directory
There are 2 IIS servers in my internal network. I created a virtual directory among them. 2 of my servers are connected to active directory. I granted the necessary permissions and gave full permission to read, write and modify the virtual directory.
I can view files on IIS server A with a virtual directory on server B. But I need to save files from server B to server A directory. I cannot add it because IIS_IUSRS does not have permission in the virtual directory on server B. How can I configure this authorization? Or do I need to give another authorization from active directory?
I would be happy if you help. Sorry my bad english.
I made authorizations between 2 servers. Files can be viewed on sites, but when I upload files from site B, it is not registered in site A directory.

This should be a permission issue. I suggest you grant the account permissions in the application pool. IIS_IUSRS may pose a security risk.

The IIS_IUSRS user exists but server A does. The IIS_IUSRS user of server B does not appear.

What I mean is that server B needs to have access to server A, but this permission does not recommend using IIS_IUSRS because this poses a security risk. My suggestion is to use the identity in the application pool of server A.
